# Where is the content of a deleted SO answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, timeline

I had this question a while back:
[How to access the SMS storage on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809874/how-to-access-the-sms-storage-on-android/15177925)

And someone answered the question.  I forget what the answer was, but I'm positive it was answered. So after a little searching, I realized I can see the history of a question timeline

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4809874/timeline

Clicking open every triangle, and I see I accepted an answer from [Sebastian Paaske Tørholm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/79061/sebastian-paaske-torholm) at `Jan 26 '11 21:32`.  But what is the answer?  How can I view the answer for myself?

Perhaps more philosophically, who/why/when was this deleted and why is that information hard to find?

Comment: Why is my **question** being downvoted?

Comment: see [vote difference](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: In a database somewhere. The rest of your questions are answered by Bill.

Comment: @eternalmatt Probably because you were being a bit of an ass towards Bill in the comments under his answer...

Answer (score 11):

The answer posted by Sebastian consisted of nothing more than three links, two of which are now broken.  This is why we consider link-only answers generally unhelpful.  A moderator left a note for Sebastian to try and fix up the answer so it can be restored.

> ...and why is that information hard to find?

Once you gain 10K reputation you'll be able to see deleted posts and that information will be easy to find.  Frankly, in the case of posts that don't answer the question, there's not much to see.

---

For what it's worth, here's a copy of [that particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4809910/105971):

> A [tutorial](http://mobdev.olin.edu/mobdevwiki/FrontPage/Tutorials/SMS%20Messaging) on how to access the SMS/MMS database, as well as send SMS'es is available from the MobDev wiki.
>
> For a concrete example of it in use, take a look at [gTalkSMS](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms). The file to look at for SMS database queries is the [SmsMmsManager](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/source/browse/src/com/googlecode/gtalksms/data/sms/SmsMmsManager.java).

Comment: My question was "Where is the content of a deleted SO answer?" Will you please delete your answer, as it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @eternalmatt Bill's answer addresses the questions in the body of your question: "who/why/when was this deleted and why is that information hard to find?". As for "Where is the content of a deleted SO answer?"... I'm not sure what you're looking for there. It's in our database?

Comment: "How can I view the answer for myself?"

Comment: @eternalmatt "Once you gain 10K reputation you'll be able to see deleted posts"

Comment: Ain't nobody got time for that.

Comment: @eternalmatt FWIW, I edited a copy of the answer as it currently stands into Bill's answer.

Comment: FWIW, I am pleased you posted the hard coded content of Sebastian's answer, but the linkage to the answer 4809910 doesn't lead anywhere for the commoners. So the general case of finding/viewing deleted answers is still open.

Comment: @eternalmatt: If that's your question, this should probably be a feature request to lower the threshold of the "view deleted posts" privilege to below 10k. Does that sound right?

Comment: @eternalmatt It's not really an issue. If everyone could view a deleted post, it wouldn't really be deleted at all, would it? This behaviour is entirely by design.

Comment: Freedom of Information Act request?

Comment: Sure, it's great that its hidden by design because the privileged decided it was unworthy of the unworthies' eyes, but if the layman were so determined to go to a timeline, he's still unable to view answer?  He'll have to put in what began as a bug report to view an answer that was at one time considered accepted? Just open up the data yeesh.

Comment: @eternalmatt: If you really want to have that discussion, you should probably edit your main question to turn it into a feature request to that effect.

Comment: @eternalmatt The timeline isn't really supported. It's an unlinked "power user" route. You did the right thing far as chasing down a specific removed answer is concerned - you came to meta. I edited the answer to remove the broken parts and undeleted it. The final result is not great, but such is life. Heavily-link-based answers are why we can't have nice things...err...long-lasting, unbroken Q&A.

Comment: Thanks for hunting down this bug Anna!

Comment: I remember when someone deleted an answer because the answer was a link. 
I told that person not to "help" because they weren't helping. He said that he cared about StackOverflow more than me.

But what did it do to the motivation of that poor soul who tried to answer my question? I think the authors of SO could use someone with charm come in and give them some lessons on how to work with people.

Comment: 10,000!?  I've been an active participant in StackOverflow for years and I'm not up to 10,000 rep yet.  I guess that makes me a loser.

Comment: @eternalmatt Hunting down what bug?

Comment: @Phillip I wouldn't say that. It just means you don't have to look at the litter of deleted posts at the bottom of many pages.  :)